# Securing USB or external HDD mounts with a password (open-source solutions)

Tags: encryption, mount, disk-encryption, password-protection, external-drive

I would like to have a password required each time I mount a USB drive or memory stick onto a Windows Vista or 7 computer.

It seems to me like I would need an encrypting filesystem: move everything outside of the external device (e.g. copy it to your PC, format the external device with the encrypting filesystem, setting the password, and copy the stuff back.

Or are there other solutions I am not aware of?

I don't want to use the proprietary sandisk or maxtor algorithms that came with the drive. Rather, I am looking for an open source solution that works well.

Thanks.

Comment: There are numerous solutions to acomplish FDE I suggest you use one of those.

Comment: Yes but which one should I use. Windows EFS seems to be not available on Windows 7 Home Premium devices. Who knows if perhaps an external program can accomplish the same job. Also, if this were possible, could I still be able to read the EFS partition from Linux? Thanks.

Comment: EFS isn't FDE though and I specifically suggested FDE. There are only a couple supported working (although with limitations) cross-platform FDE solutions.  If you use EFS you won't accomplish a password prompt nor would it support cross-platform

Comment: What are the limitations of cross-platform FDE. Are you saying I'm better of with the proprietary solution that came with my SanDisk USB device?

Comment: Limitations as in none of them support EFI/GPT

Comment: Seems like BitLocker would work well here even though it's not open source or cross-platform. TrueCrypt might too, though the security of that solution seems to be in question.

Comment: There are current forms of Truecrypt so that isn't really a problem

Comment: What is EFI/GPT? I asked for open-source solutions.